# How to create 3D Rectangle in Photoshop CC 2015

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, 3d

I am not familiar with the new 3D option that Photoshop CC 2015 provided.
I am trying to create a simple rectangle box in the 3D environment but I could not figure out how. My guess is that I could alter the Cube shape in order to create a rectangle shape in 3D mode.

Could someone help me with it?

Thank you so much for your time!

LS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do or where you're stuck, but to get you started:

- Create a rectangle, in this case I made a shape

[image]

- Go to 3D > New 3D Extrusion From Path, which will give you this (it helps to change to the 3D workspace, when prompted):

[image]

- Rotate, scale, alter your 3D shape as you wish

[image]

If you mean that you wish to alter the shape *after*  you've made the 3D version, click on the Edit Source button:

[image]

This will open your original shape in a new window (as a .psb), the same way double-clicking on a smart object would.  Make your changes to the shape in the new window, save, and close.

[image]

The changes are applied to the 3D shape when you save the .psb file

[image]